# Fallback for empty custom fields

Tags: custom-field

I'm using, for example: `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Pricing_Land_Only", true); ?>` but need to know how to implement the 'else' function to display 'Nothing found' if I didn't type anything in that field.

The reason being is for different pricing fields that I have and while not all pages use the same fields, most would. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
// store post meta in a variable and use that so you aren't pulling the post meta data twice
$landPricing = get_post_meta($post->ID, "Pricing_Land_Only", true)
if(!empty($landPricing))
{
    echo $landPricing;
}
else
{
    echo "Sorry, nothing was found.";
}
```

Comment: why not just store everything in a variable, then check the variable instead of calling get_post_meta twice?

Comment: For some reason, WP didn't like me doing that, or I added it incorrectly: `Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home/toasterd/public_html/bctderezzed.co/wp-content/themes/trece/tour-template.php on line 83` when entered as `<?php if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, "Pricing_Land_Only", true)))
{
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Pricing_Land_Only", true);
}
else
{
    echo "TBD or not applicable";
} ?>`

Comment: Thanks @BrianFegter, I definitely wasn't thinking very clearly when I wrote that out.

toasterdroid please see my updated answer, as I think what I originally showed you would break as you have seen.